# Widget sizes are inconsistent across devices even with MediaQuery.of(context)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having a problem with my app resolution. The cards I use on my Pageview and GridList have different sizes depending on the device I'm using. I want them to be the same regardless of the device's type and size.

I'm using

```
Mediaquery.of<context).size 
Mediaquery.of<context).devicePixelRatio
```

to get the device's height, width and pixel ratio.

These are the prints associated with the devices I use:

```
Emulator (Pixel 3a):
I/flutter (11909): height: 759.2727272727273
I/flutter (11909): width: 392.72727272727275
I/flutter (11909): pixel ratio: 2.75

My phone (Galaxy S9):
I/flutter ( 8712): height: 692.0
I/flutter ( 8712): width: 360.0
I/flutter ( 8712): pixel ratio: 3.0
```

My screen resolution on S9 is actually FHD+ 2220x1080, the same resolution from Pixel 3a. I don't know why it's displaying that low resolution and why they are different too! That makes no sense.

This is my code: (It's all inside a CustomScrollView)

```dart
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Text(
      I18n.of(context).bestSelling,
      style: kHeaderTextStyle,
    ),
  ),
),
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Container(
    height: screenSize.height / 3.5,
    child: PageView.builder(
      controller: PageController(
        initialPage: 1,
        viewportFraction: 0.14*screenRatio,
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: bestProducts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ProductCardBS(bestProducts[index]);
      },
    ),
  ),
),
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Text(
      I18n.of(context).sales,
      style: kHeaderTextStyle,
    ),
  ),
),
SliverPadding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 24,
    right: 24,
    bottom: 8.0,
  ),
  sliver: SliverGrid(
    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
      (_, index) {
        return ProductCard(saleProducts[index]);
      },
      childCount: saleProducts.length,
    ),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: 6.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
      childAspectRatio: 0.215 * screenRatio,
    ),
  ),
),
```

I also tried to change the screenRatio to screenSize.height but i'm getting different sizes either way.

These are the pics associated with the code, the first one is from my S9, the second from Pixel 3a:

[image] [image]

Notice how the heights from the cards are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media query does not give you the number of physical pixels. That is why your screen has 2220x1080 pixels but it will say that its less.

If you want the exact pixel count you can use the `window` singleton from `dart:ui`.

```
var screenSize = window.physicalSize;
```

and use a `SizedBox` widget to force a widget to an exact size.

Also, you should probably not multiply viewportFraction with anything. it's already a percentage of your screen.

```dart
viewportFraction: 0.14*screenRatio, -> viewportFraction: 0.14,
```

There is also a widget called `FractionallySizedBox` that is always taking the same fraction of the screen:

```dart
FractionallySizedBox(
      heightFactor: 0.2,
      widthFactor: 0.28,
      child: ...,
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the solution!